# react classname 3 conditional rendering hide with display none

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 variables that I must evaluate to hide a div if a condition is met between these 3 variables, something like this:

```
appState.fullResults
appState.someResults
appState.otherResults
```

So, when `appState.fullResults` and `appState.someResults` come empty, but `appState.otherResults` has something, I need to hide a div, this code snippet is an example:

```
<div classname='container'>
<div classname='full-some'>
boxes
</div>
<divclassname='others'>
boxes
</div>
</div>
```

I try something like this, but dont work

```
className={`${
                        (!appState.someResults?.length > 0 && otherResults?.length > 0)
                          ? 'container-boxcard'
                          : 'd-none'
                      }`}
```

I always get the same result: if othersResults brings something and someResults brings nothing, the "d-none" is not passed to hide it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wco8p.jpg
Still evaluates false and applies the d-none class

Hope I have explained well, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it was a problem with the function that created the objects fullResults, someResults & otherResults, it was passing all the answer to the object, creating another object inside, that's why always the object even if it had no data inside, evaluated length greater than 0 because it had something inside,

```
setAppQuotationState({
      loading: false,
      fullResults: fullResults?.length > 0 ? [fullResults] : [],
      someResults: someResults?.length > 0 ? [someResults] : [],
      otherResults: otherResults?.length > 0 ? [otherResults] : [],
    })
  }
```

correcting that bug, the solutions that I indicated, worked well.

Answer (score 1):

`!appState.someResults?.length > 0` is hard to understand, I'd suggest you should change it to `!appState.someResults?.length` or `appState.someResults?.length === 0` (you can choose one of them).

I haven't seen you declared `otherResults` anywhere else, so I'd assume that `otherResults?.length > 0` should be `appState.otherResults?.length` (or `appState.otherResults?.length > 0`).

```
className={`${(!appState.someResults?.length && appState.otherResults?.length)
               ? 'd-none'
               : 'container-boxcard'
}`}
```

> when appState.fullResults and appState.someResults come empty, but appState.otherResults has something

According to your demonstration, you can follow this with 3 conditions

```
className={`${(!appState.someResults?.length && !appState.fullResults?.length && appState.otherResults?.length)
               ? 'd-none'
               : 'container-boxcard'
}`}
```

Comment: With this code, its gets evaluated false, even if someResults has length
https://imgur.com/bZBUGo9
still applies d-none

Comment: Could you verify the above modifed code again? @CodeAgainst

Comment: nopes, still gets truthy, even if someResults.lenght its 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
const { fullResults, someResults, otherResults } = appState;
const className = !fullResults?.length && !someResults?.length
&& otherResults?.length ? 'd-none' : 'container-boxcard';
<YourComponent className={className} {...props} />
```

Comment: With this code, its gets evaluated false, even if someResults has length
https://imgur.com/bZBUGo9
still applies d-none

Comment: but that's what i understood you wanna achieve ! please tell me your edge cases to see how we can translate it to a proper code